# Online Tool for creating a sequence diagram in Mac

Tags: iphone, objective-c

Sorry this is not a programming question. I want to develop a sequence diagram for my iOS application.

I googled a lot but couldn't find any helpful tool

Can anyone please help me with any online tool or any other tool for creating a sequence diagram in Mac.

Comment: https://www.genmymodel.com is now supporting sequence diagrams and works under any operating systems including MacOS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a useful tool.  Please navigate to [here](https://cacoo.com/r/KmWnV)

```
  [1]: https://cacoo.com/r/KmWnV
```